# Error running Java EE application with GlassFish: NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Tags: java, dependencies, apache-commons-logging

When trying to run a Java EE application with GlassFish, I encounter the following error on the server:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.<init>(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:72)
    ...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at dynamics365.TokenGenerator.ejecutarTokenGenerator(TokenGenerator.java:62)
    at sessionBeans.ParametroFacade.buscarCliente(ParametroFacade.java:103)
        at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)
    ...
```

What I've tried:

- I have reviewed the project configuration to make sure all dependencies are configured correctly.
- I have removed the use of Apache Commons Logging as it appears to be the cause of the problem.
- I have cleaned and rebuilt the project to make sure there are no outdated build artifacts.
- I've reviewed the project structure and GlassFish server configuration to ensure everything is in order.

Wait:

I am looking for help to fix this error and understand why it occurs. Is there something I'm overlooking in my configuration or dependency management? How can I resolve this issue and run my application without this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was reload all the JAR into the lib of the payara domains, restart it and from there, clean and build the project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for help to fix this error and understand why it occurs.

It is happening because *something* in your application and/or its dependencies depends on that `LogFactory` class.  That is indisputable.

As best as I can tell, your class `TokenGenerator` is still making use of Apache Commons Logging. That is what the stacktrace seems to say.

So either:

1. the stacktrace is out of date,
2. the copy of `TokenGenerator.class` that is being used at runtime is out of date, or
3. you forgot to update `TokenGenerator.java`.

On the other hand, if `TokenGenerator.java` is not your code, then you need to modify the project configuration so that the JAR file for Apache Commons Logging is present at runtime!

> Is there something I'm overlooking in my configuration or dependency management?

Quite possibly.  For example, you have only told us what *you think* you did and checked.  You haven't shown us the configuration or dependency management stuff, etc.

> How can I resolve this issue and run my application without this error?

Either remove the remaining references to the dependency from your application and its (transitive!) dependencies **that must exist**, or make sure that the requisite JAR is included.

---

(I am assuming that there aren't other exceptions that you haven't told us about; i.e. exceptions resulting from failed static initialization that happened **before** this one.  A static initialization failure for a class will render other classes uninitializable, and that can result in cascading exceptions.)